# how do i animate one mesh turning into another

Tags: animation

Im doing a small project for a friend where im animating a logo in the style of the logo at the end of the [transformers prime opening](https://youtu.be/ltpfxkcNYI4) where at first it is a blocky, cubic random shape that turns into the logo, i already have the logo modeled and i animated its movement, and i will model the cubic shape next. I would just like to know how i can make one shape turn into the other.

Comment: You are probably looking for what Blender calls [Shape Keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html). They let you morph a mesh into another mesh which is why they are also called Morph Targets or Blend Shapes.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)